# JavaScript jQuery AJAX POST data error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a post param. to `request.php` but it returns that the post param. are empty.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
$.ajax({
    url: "request.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "{key:'123', action:'getorders'}",
    contentType: "multipart/form-data",
    complete: alert("complete"),
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: alert("error")
});
```

Comment: try data : {'key':'123', 'action':'getorders'}

Comment: remove `" "` from this data format `data:"{key:'123', action:'getorders'}"`

Comment: didn't work @DavidJawphan

Comment: @Vishnu same prob.. key is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `FormData` for `multipart/form-data` ,and also need additional option in ajax ..

```
var request = new FormData();   
request.append('key',123);
request.append('action','getorders');
$.ajax({
    url: "request.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: request,    
    processData : false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 5):

remove " " from this data as `data:{key:'123', action:'getorders'}`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     $.ajax({
        url:"request.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{key:'123', action:'getorders'},
        contentType:"multipart/form-data",
        complete:alert("complete"),
        success:function(data) {
          alert(data);
            },
        error:alert("error")
             }); 

          </script>
```

Comment: you can false contentType as you want then it should work

Answer (score 1):

This will help you. You don't want a string, you really want a JS map of key value pairs.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
       url:"request.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:{key:'123', action:'getorders'},
       contentType:"multipart/form-data",
       complete:alert("complete"),
       success:function(data) {
          alert(data);
       },
       error:function(){
          alert("error");
       }); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work like a champ ,
construct object as below and `stringify` it as `JSON.stringify(newObject)` then there will be no chance of error

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       var newObject= new Object();
       newObject.key= '123';
       newObject.action='getorders'
        $.ajax({
           url:"request.php",
           type:"POST",
           data:JSON.stringify(newObject),
           contentType:"multipart/form-data",
           complete:alert("complete"),
           success:function(data) {
              alert(data);
           },
           error:function(){
              alert("error");
           }); 

    </script>
```

Comment: still key is empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({key: '123', action: 'getorders'}),
contentType: "application/json"
```

Comment: tried it... it return nothing.. even the "key is empty"

Comment: Try to verify the url.
Also share the error received.

Comment: $.ajax({
    url: "request.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: '{ "key":"123", "action": "getorders"}',
    contentType: "application/json",
    complete: alert("complete"),
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}
});

Please note: In JSON - Strings (Key names and string values etc) are present in double quotes (" ") and not in single quote.